# Crystal Reports 2011 Charts

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a problem with pie charts in Crystal 2011. I have created a reports that pulls in service tickets for our customers and displays them grouped by how many tickets came in per site. Each customer has hundreds of sites that we differentiate by concept.

I have used suppress to hide all instances of other customers in the detail section expert so we can provide reports to each individual customer. The only problem I face is that when trying to add a chart it also displays all suppressed data.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction on only displaying the concept I choose?

I tried using the same suppress formula in the section where the chart resides but it removes the entire chart.

Comment: I have placed it in the footer. The problem is it populates with data Ive suppressed in the rest of the report and suppressing it in the footer removes the chart

Answer (score 0):

Suppression of rows in details doesn't change what is used in the chart.

You have two options:

Option 1: Make a subreport for each chart and use the chart data to make your chart(s)

Option 2: Create a cross-tab where only the column and summarized field is populated. Then under Column, Group Options, change sort to Specified Order. Go to Specified Order tab, and pick your one customer. Under Others tab, choose Discard All Others. Right click on Cross-Tab and Insert Chart. Suppress the report header or footer that has your Cross Tab.

Comment: I think this may work. Only issue Im having is I cannot select cross tab as the data source for some reason. It is grayed out.